# groupby with overlapping intervals timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, time-series

I have a time series in python pandas dataframe object and I want to create a group based on index but I want overlapping groups i.e groups are not distinct. The  header_sec is the index column.
Each groups consists of a 2 second window. 
 Input dataFrame

```
    header_sec
1  17004 days 22:17:13 
2  17004 days 22:17:13 
3  17004 days 22:17:13 
4  17004 days 22:17:13 
5  17004 days 22:17:14
6  17004 days 22:17:14
7  17004 days 22:17:14
8  17004 days 22:17:14
9  17004 days 22:17:15
10 17004 days 22:17:15
11 17004 days 22:17:15
12 17004 days 22:17:15
13 17004 days 22:17:16
14 17004 days 22:17:16
15 17004 days 22:17:16
16 17004 days 22:17:16
17 17004 days 22:17:17
18 17004 days 22:17:17
19 17004 days 22:17:17
20 17004 days 22:17:17
```

My first group should have

```
1  17004 days 22:17:13 
2  17004 days 22:17:13 
3  17004 days 22:17:13 
4  17004 days 22:17:13 
5  17004 days 22:17:14
6  17004 days 22:17:14
7  17004 days 22:17:14
8  17004 days 22:17:14
```

The second group starts from the previous index and takes 1/2 of the records in previous second.

```
7  17004 days 22:17:14
8  17004 days 22:17:14
9  17004 days 22:17:15
10 17004 days 22:17:15
11 17004 days 22:17:15
12 17004 days 22:17:15
13 17004 days 22:17:16
14 17004 days 22:17:16
```

Third group .....

```
13 17004 days 22:17:16
14 17004 days 22:17:16
15 17004 days 22:17:16
16 17004 days 22:17:16
17 17004 days 22:17:17
18 17004 days 22:17:17
19 17004 days 22:17:17
20 17004 days 22:17:17
```

If I do groupby on index,

```
  dfgroup=df.groupby(df.index)
```

this gives one group per second. What would be the best way to merge these groups?

Comment: Are there always going to be 4 entries per second?

Comment: No, since there is missing data. These are actually samples collected per second.  The actual data has 100 samples per second but sometimes there is a missing entry.

Comment: Examples in your question are not consistent. Second group takes 2 rows from 22:17:14, but third group does not take any from 22:17:15. First group takes all values from 22:17:15, but second group does not take all values from 22:17:16. Can you please clarify? I am thinking, what you need is all values from a given second + last 2 values from previous second + first 2 values from next second. Correct?

Comment: Each group consists of a 2 second window, but it moves in an overlapping way, where only half of the entries of a previous second go in next set. Hence take 1/2 entries from previous second + current second + 1/2 entries from next second. Third group takes 1/2 of the entries of previous second i.e entry number 13 and 14 are repeated  giving 13-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a technique:

```
import numpy as np # if you have not already done this

grouped = df.groupby(df.index)

for name, group in grouped:
    try:
        prev_sec = df.loc[(name - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='s')), :]
    except KeyError:
        prev_sec = pd.DataFrame(columns=group.columns)
    try:
        next_sec = df.loc[(name + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='s')), :]
    except KeyError:
        next_sec = pd.DataFrame(columns=group.columns)
    Pn = 2 # replace this with int(len(prev_sec)/2) to get half rows from previous second
    Nn = 2 # replace this with int(len(next_sec)/2) to get half rows from next second
    group = pd.concat([prev_sec.iloc[-Pn:,:], group, next_sec.iloc[:Nn,:]])

    # Replace the below lines with your operations
    print(name, group)
```

Comment: I get an error at this line                                                                                           prev_sec = df[df['header_sec'].isin(name - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='s'))]    since "header sec" is the index and not  a column. I tried replacing it  to  df[df[df.index].isin(name - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='s'))]  but still gives a key error  "TimedeltaIndex(['17004 days 22:17:13', '17004 days 22:17:13',\n                '17004 days 22:17:13', '17004 days  .....                           not in index"

Comment: Edited my answer. You need `df[df.index.isin(...)]`.

Comment: I tried that too but it still gives an error                                                                  only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [Timedelta]. This is because my index is already timedelta.                     This is what I do before groupby                                                                   df.loc[:,['header_stamp_secs_x']] = pd.to_timedelta(df.header_stamp_secs_x, unit='s')
df.set_index('header_stamp_secs_x', inplace=True)

Comment: Oh yeah... That. Sorry for the oversight. The name is just a single entity, not a list. My mistake, I sincerely apologize for the back and forth. The edit to the answer should work.

Comment: sorry for being novice with dataframes, but it did not work. I think because my index is timedelta and it says  only list-like objects are allowed to to be passed to isin(), you passed a [timedelta64]                                                                                                                                                                             
  print type(name - np.timedelta64(1, 's'))                                                               <type 'numpy.timedelta64'>

Comment: No, you don't have to apologize for anything. I was too hasty in answering your question, and made mistakes. The edited answer has been tested and should work.