# pandas rolling groupby timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387052/create-overlapping-groups-with-pandas-timegrouper) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883465/groupby-with-overlapping-intervals-timeseries) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912524/pandas-dataframe-groupby-overlapping-intervals-of-variable-length) related questions but none seem to be doing the trick. I want a similar implementation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247009/window-overlap-in-pandas) but with the pandas dataframe structure. Below I create sample data from the entire 2016 year, which has 366 rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   
dates=pd.date_range('2016-01-01','2016-12-31')    
random_data=np.random.randn(len(dates))
data=pd.DataFrame(random_data,index=dates,columns=['Test'])
```

I would like to use groupby to get the next 5 days of data every 2 days. Normal groupby does not have overlapping timframes; putting in a groupby of 2 days will give me 183 (366/2) groups that have two days data. Putting a groupby of 5 days will give me around 74 (366/5) groups that have 5 days each. I would like 183 groups that have five days each.

Sorry in advance if this is not clear. Here is what I want:

```
            Test
2016-02-08  1.073696
2016-02-09  1.169865
2016-02-10  1.421454
2016-02-11 -0.576036
2016-02-12 -1.066921

            Test
2016-02-10  1.421454
2016-02-11 -0.576036
2016-02-12 -1.066921
2016-02-13  2.639681
2016-02-14 -0.261616
```

This is what I get with `data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('2d'))`

```
            Test
2016-02-08  1.073696
2016-02-09  1.169865
            Test
2016-02-10  1.421454
2016-02-11 -0.576036
            Test
2016-02-12 -1.066921
2016-02-13  2.639681
```

This is what I get with `data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5d'))`

```
            Test
2016-02-08  0.898029
2016-02-09 -0.905950
2016-02-10 -0.202483
2016-02-11  1.073696
2016-02-12  1.169865
                Test
2016-02-13  1.421454
2016-02-14 -0.576036
2016-02-15 -1.066921
2016-02-16  2.639681
2016-02-17 -0.261616
```

Comment: If any of those answers are helpful, feel free to up-vote them as well as @Psidom's answer below.  If you think you are looking for something different, let me know and I'll open this back up.

Comment: Thank you, I missed your question while googling. Is there a way to add more keywords like 'rolling' or 'groupby' so google your question up over the other ones I linked?

Comment: Your question does exactly that.  You've added key words.  When people google for something that would lead them to this question, Stackoverflow redirects that traffic to my question, all because I marked it as a duplicate.  This is why its ok to ask duplicates.  You asked an identical question but with different wording.  In that sense, you've helped improve the site.

Comment: Also, I've asked a bunch of numpy questions that got marked as duplicates because I can never think of the right words to search for to find what I'm looking for

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dates are normal sequence with difference of one day as your sample data shows, you can use index to pick up the rows. *Start from every two rows and  select five rows for each pick*:

```
[data.iloc[i:(i+5)] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]

#[                Test
# 2016-01-01  0.450173
# 2016-01-02 -0.496819
# 2016-01-03  0.270781
# 2016-01-04 -0.207634
# 2016-01-05  1.032061,                 
#                 Test
# 2016-01-03  0.270781
# 2016-01-04 -0.207634
# 2016-01-05  1.032061
# 2016-01-06 -0.470462
# 2016-01-07 -1.077634, ...]
```

Comment: If you added that to the other post, I'd up vote it there as well.